# Issue with JSON Schema object validation (How does it work internally)?

Tags: json, jsonschema

**BACKGROUND:**
I have mockedup my issue here for reference:
https://jsonschemalint.com/#/version/draft-06/markup/json?gist=4c185903d7aeb13f6977852a09cf5462

and I am using this npm package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonschema

**CODE**

```
//i read in JSON specified in files (the contents of which are below) and parse them into JSON objects. This process works fine.

var jsonDef = JSON.parse(schemaFile); //i store this jsonDef in my database as an object
var jsonObj = JSON.parse(objFile);
var jsonv = new JSONValidator();

var validateResult = jsonv.validate(jsonObj, jsonDef); //jsonDef is read from my database
//validateResult.valid is true
```

**PROBLEM:**
I have a general schema + metadata definition like so (`"props"` contains the actual object schema I want to validate)

schemaFile:

```
{
    "name":"schoolDemo",
    "displayName":"School Demo",
    "propertiesKey":"assetId",
    "props":{       
        "assetId": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "grade": {
            "type": "number"
        }
    }
}
```

objFile:

```
{
    "assetId": "75255972",
    "grade": "A"    
}
```

However, when I try to validate against the following user-input object, it succeeds. **Shouldn't it fail because:**

(1) there is no `"properties"` element in the initial metadata+schema definition? This field seems to be required based on the examples shown here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonschema

(2) the `type` for `grade` is not a `number`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The validation is passing because the schema is not well formed ("properties" is missing).

Try this instead and then the validation will fail:

```
{
  "name": "schoolDemo",
  "displayName": "School Demo",
  "propertiesKey": "assetId",
  "properties": {
    "assetId": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "grade": {
      "type": "number"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: (1) that is odd, but seems correct (shouldn't a malformed schema fail?).  
      (2) And is "properties" like a reserved word, for the jsonschema package? Do I need to perform a check to make sure there is 1 and only 1 top level "properties" property in the JSON object I'm trying to validate?

Comment: (1) the schema is malformed in a way that it's not validating anything. This is why it's passing.

Comment: (2) "properties" is a reserved word to indicate this is an object that contains child (like assetId and grade).